# ¿cómo puedo asignar una IP estática (red local) a un contenedor Docker para que sea accesible desde toda mi red local?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, networking, docker-machine

Me explico, quiero desplegar un contenedor Docker en mi red local (192.168.0.0) y que sea accesible desde toda la red. Es una configuración sencilla en máquinas virtuales, simplemente se cambia el adaptador de red a "adaptador puente" y la máquina ya está en tu red local. Espero que me puedan ayudar porque he buscado por todos lados y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.